# Use the for attribute of a label to reference a control inside a repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to utilize the `for` attribute of the label element inside of a repeater, but since the referenced control is `runat="server"` the id is changed in the referenced control but not in the label that is referencing it using the `for` attribute.

This:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary active" runat="server" id="lblForm" for="cbForm">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="cbForm" runat="server"/>
    <label>
        <%#Container.DataItem.Title%>
    </label>
</label>
```

gets rendered to:

```
<label id="afForms_rptForms_ctl00_lblForm" class="btn btn-primary active" for="cbForm">
    <input name="afForms$rptForms$ctl00$cbForm" type="checkbox" id="afForms_rptForms_ctl00_cbForm" autocomplete="off">
    <label>
        Some String Value Here
    </label>
</label>
```

So now the label is no longer for the designated checkbox control since the id was changed by .net. How do I keep the `for` attributed current with the id of the control is it for when .net changes the id? I do not want to change the ClientIDMode to Static since I will have multiple labels/checkboxes and that would create duplicate id values in the repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is what I ended up doing inside my repeater ItemDataBound event to make this work.

```
Protected Sub rptForms_ItemDataBound(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptForms.ItemDataBound
    Dim lblForm As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblForm"), HtmlGenericControl)
    Dim cb As HtmlInputCheckBox = CType(e.Item.FindControl("cbForm"), HtmlInputCheckBox)
    lblForm.Attributes.Item("for") = cb.ClientID
End Sub
```